# Days calculation difference in flutter json Api date - current date

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

**I am fetching one date-format from json Api  and another date is current date i wants the difference in days like this eg;-**

`server_date=2020-04-18T17:26:33.150;
current_date=2020-05-07;
var days=server_date - current date;`

`Json Api "CLMM_LAST_ACTIVITY_DT": "2020-04-18T17:26:33.150",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use difference method of dataTime.

following code help you more.

```
 String server_date = "2020-04-18T17:26:33.150";
 DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
 int days = currentTime.difference(DateTime.parse(server_date)).inDays;
 print(days);
```

Comment: sure, if i can. what is issue ?

Comment: check out this articale.https://medium.com/flutterdevs/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-b7f991611d3e